# Azure worker role suddenly stops and starts again and stops again without leaving clear errors on the logs

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

We're currently developing an Azure Cloud Service that is composed of two Worker Roles and a Web Role.

One of the Worker Roles receives TCP messages from MEITRACK car gps tracking devices. The services has been developed for an initial iteration and works fine in the development environment, but when deployed to Azure the worker role sometimes suddenly stops receiving messages, and sometimes it starts again and stops again, without leaving clear errors on the logs.

This was the Base application used to build the service: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Azure-Multi-Tier-eadceb36

Has someone worked with Azure Worker Roles and have any idea why it stops and starts itself.

Comment: Purely speculating (as there's no code to see in the question), my guess is that your application is encountering an unhandled exception which is causing the endless loop in which worker role is running to break which in turn causing your worker role to restart. If you have enabled Azure Diagnostics, I would suggest connecting to the Worker Role instance using RDP and check the event logs. I'm quite sure that you will find something there.

Comment: You should wrap `OnStart()`, `Run()` and `OnStop()` payloads into try-catch and log whatever exceptions you catch there. This will be much more efficient than trying to guess. And keep that code in there - it will save you a lot of pain in the future.

Comment: Hello @GauravMantri & sharptooth.
We have all our code with a try/catch and no appears errors when the worker role stops... Simply it stops receiving messages and no more info.
Any other ideas?

Comment: @Gabrielizalo Did you find a solution/work around for this problem?

Comment: OMG. @JawadSabir sorry... I was a lot of years ago. I don't remember. :'(